# How to get property value assigned in function definition to property decorator

Tags: typescript

I am new to using decorators in typescript, I am using property decorator and when this property changes later, I want decorator to receive this new value. But decorator is not invoked!, I want decorator to receive newly assigned value, any help how to do it ?

Here is what I have tried

```
function ModifyMessage(sender: string) {
    console.log(`message received: ${sender}`);
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {

        let modifiedMessage: string;

        const getter = function () {
            return modifiedMessage;
        };
        
        const setter = function () {
            modifiedMessage = `Hello from ${sender}!`;
        };


        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter
        });
    }
}


class Greeter {
    @ModifyMessage("some random")
    firstMessage: string;
    
    modifyMsg(msg) {
        this.firstMessage = msg;
    }

    greet() {
        console.log(`first message: ${this.firstMessage}`);
    }
}
  
let myGreeter = new Greeter();
myGreeter.modifyMsg('new World');//expected this to trigger decorator and get Hello from new World! but getting Hello from some random!
myGreeter.greet();
```

This is ts.config

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "ES5",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter isn't actually updating the message. You need to be taking the first argument:

```
const setter = function (sender: string) {
    modifiedMessage = `Hello from ${sender}!`;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWTgExsAnsgpgZ3wEMBzXACn1zDVwCcAuRfKOmMEgSkQG8AoRIMQQE+OABtcAOnFwS5AAYBbAsTKI6uCLhgA3XGiYASHlRr0Avgs4BuAUM1QQdJKEiwEiclCJ0yUJiIwLAAaRAAHOjhw+igsAGlcLCYWNg5ufiEsxEkoRCV0TBgDPEJSXBTWdhI7e2zhUTz-KHpEAF5EN2h4JHIMuvqHXCcXfMLgYrRStVw7QcQLWvmRMBZmYZa6ds7wbs9KalpGZir03gH5gowJktVy7YUACVxxWU6opUQTMyOLAEIFHNBos+BchAB5ABGACstFApLQJmBcAAFKIxOhxby+fxhSLRWIJJJhTLzIT+JjNeghMH1KgBdZQTY0+YWWwDEEWUEQcREQiIADimmGrVJggAAqhrjg7mRyAAiMQqDRBNBwJTyzgDCZ0FjTcp-SppGqgrJXTA4fDyJRWo3VfrzKAACxg+CkOr1stw2xtJqyXIGJGFUD652Wogk0lk8gUHryKjKZGMPGdrvdMF1UH1ZCs7P9fADuXyWCFuBFWw6yIA7oLg-Q+nYlCW63QpObsMgrQrq4gAOpwOjiNCamyIAD0Y9wAA8YtADIhU-gF3AF2wSGQtrQRHQiFAB4hVYh-Ihnq8V8APoge-3B2g-ohISAmhtqieXm8L+rmOrvTuaOq-j4JtS3LKQgzLEN2SAA)